# How do I flatten this json grouped by headers so I can present this data in a more understandable way?

Tags: javascript, json

I know, there are plenty of questions on traversing arbitrary json data in Javascript. BUT, I need to present the data in a more understandable way?

EDIT: The json is gonna be arbitrary...a mix of nested objects, arrays, strings, etc. I just need to group each level together

[my fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcb8yxft/) and is very basic. It just splits out a bunch of rows:

```
symbol
financials.0.date
financials.0.Revenue
financials.0.Revenue Growth
financials.0.Cost of Revenue
financials.0.Gross Profit
financials.0.R&D Expenses
financials.0.SG&A Expense
financials.0.Operating Expenses
financials.0.Operating Income
financials.0.Interest Expense
financials.0.Earnings before Tax
financials.0.Income Tax Expense
financials.0.Net Income - Non-Controlling int
financials.0.Net Income - Discontinued ops
financials.0.Net Income
...
...
inancials.10.Weighted Average Shs Out
financials.10.Weighted Average Shs Out (Dil)
financials.10.Dividend per Share
financials.10.Gross Margin
financials.10.EBITDA Margin
financials.10.EBIT Margin
financials.10.Profit Margin
financials.10.Free Cash Flow margin
financials.10.EBITDA
financials.10.EBIT
financials.10.Consolidated Income
financials.10.Earnings Before Tax Margin
financials.10.Net Profit Margin
AAPL
2019-09-28
2.60174e+11
0.0
1.61782e+11
98392000000.0
16217000000.0
18245000000.0
34462000000.0
63930000000.0
3576000000.0
65737000000.0
10481000000.0
0.0
0.0
55256000000.0
0.0
55256000000.0
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rows = [];
  var d = flatten(data);
  rows.push(Object.keys(d));
  rows.push(Object.values(d));

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
      var k = "<div>" + rows[i][j] + "</div>";
      if (i === 0) {
        $("#headers").append(k);
      } else {
        $("#results").append(k);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I need a format that groups the data by header, so that `financials.0.date` and `financials.1.date`, etc. are all grouped together. Something like this:
[where the data is grouped together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pVtI.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a thead element and put the th, or headers, all across.  The have your code produce the rows of data in td elements within tr elements, this will organize your code properly

Comment: The issue isn't in creating the table or divs, etc. It is in organizing the json data to output it correctly

Comment: You will have to create a for loop that loops through the headers, then a nested for loop for the data.

Comment: Each piece of data in the for loop will be for the next header, then it will loop back to create another row of data.  This way it will organize the data for you

Comment: This didn't solve it for me but helped me get a bit further. I will post another question with a better guidance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the divs, why not input the json data into table rows.  That is how the image you linked shows the data.  The headers can be in th elements, giving the same look and feel.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great! But, I still need to organized the data somehow.